# How can I draw a sector with internal radius using Turf

Tags: drawing, cesiumjs, turfjs

I know I can draw a [sector using Turf](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sector-polygon-ivcvj?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)

What I need is to give another radius information, to "cut" the internal part of the sector, like the image ( consider the red polygon my goal ).

[image]

I really need to [use Turf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/sector) and can't do complex calculations because the user will use the mouse to draw it in real time on the map.

MUST be Turf because I'm trying to extend [this tool](https://github.com/renshuo/cesium-plotting-symbol).